# MediaStore.MediaColumns.IS_FAVORITE Not Useable

Tags: android, mediastore

Above Android 11. I can.t get valid value on this column from contentProvider, anyone has information? The follow is my code:

```
private static final String[] PROJECTION_30 = {
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns._ID,
            MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,
            MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE,
            MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE,
            MediaStore.MediaColumns.WIDTH,
            MediaStore.MediaColumns.HEIGHT,
            MediaStore.MediaColumns.IS_FAVORITE};

CursorLoader(context, MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external_primary"), PROJECTION_30, selection, selectionArgs, null);

fun fromCursor(cursor: Cursor): MediaModel {
    try {
                val id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns._ID))
                val mimeType = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE))
                val size = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE))
                val width = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.WIDTH))
                val height = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.HEIGHT))
                val favorite = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                    val index = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.IS_FAVORITE)
                    if (index >= 0) {
                        cursor.getInt(index)
                    } else {
                        0
                    }
                } else {
                    0
                }
            }
        }
```

But, favorite result is aways 0

I wish i can get real favorite value from MediaStore

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the manufacturer. I can't get favorite media in device like Oppo, Xiaomi but I can get favorite media in Samsung. I guess with devices from China manufacturer, they use their DB instead of MediaStore to manage favorite.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).